# How to stop my comments from spilling out of the margin in my RMarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to stop the comments from spilling out of my RMarkdown output.

This is my working code:

````
---
title: 'This is a test title'
author:
  - name: Honk R. \orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0001}
    affil-id: 1,3
  - name: Tar F. \orcidlink{0000-0000-0000-0002}
    affil-id: 2
affiliations: 
  - id: 1
    name: Lima Beans.
  - id: 2
    name: Peas.
  - id: 3
    name: French Beans.
date: July 6, 2023
geometry:
- margin=1in
output:
  pdf_document:
    number_sections: yes
    template: default.tex
---

```{r clustering, echo=TRUE, fig.height=2.5, fig.width=3}

library(tidyverse)
library(factoextra)

# These are the libraries that I am trying the load.

Groups <-as.factor(iris$Species) # This is another attempt at a long comment to try and make it spill out of the margins.

Matrix <-as.matrix(iris[1:4]) # Defining this matrix of numbers for PCA test.

res.pca<-princomp(Matrix)

fviz_pca_biplot(res.pca,
                habillage = Groups) # This is going to be yet another attempt at making a long comment to check if it spills out of the margins so I can make my point
````

This is output:

[image: Output]

How do I stop the comments from spilling out of the margin and stead warp? Is there a global command to ensure text wrap?

Answer (score 1):

If you put your comments on their own lines instead of putting them at the end of a line containing code, then the chunk option `tidy = TRUE` will get them to wrap.  For example, this:

[image]

will be formatted like this:

[image]

The `tidy = TRUE` option won't touch your style of comment, and as far as I can see there's no way to get it to do so.  However, using `tidy = "styler"` will use the `styler` package for formatting, and it is very customizable.  I don't think it has an existing option to do what you want, but you could probably write one.

Comment: I am coming at this as a LaTeX user. RMarkdown is new for me. Is there a reason that `geometry` package can't be used to strictly define the page dimensions and just let the text wrap? 

I haven't used `styler` before. Guess that's one more package I'll have to read up about.

Comment: You can set the `keep_tex: true` option to `pdf_document` to find out what LaTeX environment it's using for code chunks.  Maybe that environment has an option to wrap text, but the default is to display it as is.  (The `styler` package changes what goes into the `.tex` file.)

Comment: Thanks. I;ll try that out. May I pick your brain for one more minor question? Is it possible to automatically out the current date?

Comment: To insert that into text, use ```r Sys.Date()```  (That should have single backticks around `r Sys.Date()`; I don't know how to get the escaping right.)  For different formatting, use `format(Sys.Date(), format = "...")`.  See `?strptime` for possible format strings, e.g. `format(Sys.Date(), format = "%B %d, %Y")` gives `"July 17, 2023"` on my system.